# How is a test expression tested?

Tags: dfdl

dfdl has `assert` and `discriminator`, each of which will allow a "test expression" to be the value of `test`. e.g.,

```
<dfdl:assert test="{test expression}" />
```

but all the documentation says about "test expressions" is about what happens when they pass or fail. meanwhile, if you look through [the official daffodil repository for GIF](https://github.com/DFDLSchemas/GIF) by mitre, gif.dfdl.xsd includes lines like

```
<dfdl:discriminator test="{(Byte1 eq 33) and (Byte2 eq 249)}"/>
```

which implies to me that it just sends the test to the shell (i.e., bash? powershell on windows? cmd on windows?) to "test" a test expression.

Is that right? if not, how *does* it test them? what's the language for these test expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test expressions use the "DFDL expression language", which is a subset of XPath 2.0. Section 18 of the DFDL specification (https://daffodil.apache.org/docs/dfdl/#_Toc322911718) details the language syntax and supported functions.

Daffodil implements a custom expression parser and evaluator in Scala (which it internally calls DPath) to efficiently support DFDL expressions.